# Simple HTML upload form Without PHP

Tags: html, file-upload, upload

I was wondering if it will b possible to Create a HTML upload form and it will be purely HTML without calling any other PHP language to validate it. for example, Normally to create a file upload form is this way. 
                               ***Create an Upload-File Form***

Look at the following HTML form for uploading files:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

While the PHP script will do the rest..

**Create The Upload Script**

The "upload_file.php" file contains the code for uploading a file: And it will look lyk dis

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
   {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
 }
?>
```

but i was wondering if it can be possible not to use a PHP script but only an HTML script for example

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.html" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

While maybe another html script will do the rest..

I hope u guys can understand my question and give me a reply, Thanks

Answer (score 5):

HTML doesn't "do" anything. You can create the *form* in HTML perfectly fine. But if nothing on the server is handling the upload, it's pointless. You need *something* server-side that does something with the uploaded data; HTML cannot.

Answer (score 2):

When a file is uploaded to the webserver via an HTML form, it is placed in a temp directory, with a temporary filename. You need a script of some sort (PHP, .jsp, Perl,...) to 'do' something with the file, like placing it in the correct directory with the correct filename. If you don't do this, the webserver will delete this file when the next url is called in your session.

Comment: Alright thanks guy. i was thinking HTML can still be  handling the upload

Comment: @Mrportal HTML is a *declarative* meta language. It doesn't *do* anything, it only describes a document format. It neither uploads anything (the browser does) nor can it handle anything server-side.

Comment: @Borniet _> "it is placed in a temp directory, with a temporary filename."_ Is it possible to set this temp file to become a permanent file? ex: set the expiration date to infinity?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need client-side scripting to validate file-upload. If it is, then I believe this [link](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/) will be helpful. Which explains, how to upload file using jQuery